# Conocer el usuario de origen de un mensaje de email a traves de DJango

Tags: django

Veran, en mi programa de DJango doy opción a que el usuario envie un mensaje que pasara a un email.

Codigo en settings.py:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'pajaritosami88@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'perritos'
```

Codigo en forms.py:

class correo(forms.Form):
    asunto=forms.CharField(required=True)
    contenido=forms.CharField(max_length=999, widget=forms.Textarea)

Codigo en views.py:

```
class contacto(View):
    def get(self,request):
        form=correo()
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
    def post(self,request):
        form=correo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            datos=form.cleaned_data
            email=EmailMessage('title','body', to=['pajaritosami88@gmail.com'])
            email.send()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
```

El resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuenta de email a que iba el mensaje es **pajaritosami88@gmail.com**. El usuario con el que hice la prueba tenia un nombre de correo distinto. ¿Que hago para que se indique el email de quien envio el mensaje?

**Edito:**

Voy a probar que la cabecera del email indique quien envia el mensaje. Para ello, primero quito la variable "asunto" del objeto en el forms.py.

```
class correo(forms.Form):
    contenido=forms.CharField(max_length=999, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Y despues modifico el codigo en views.py:

```
class contacto(View):
    def get(self,request):
        form=correo()
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
    def post(self,request):
        form=correo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cuerpo="Mensaje de "+str(User.objects.get(first_name='Sara'))
            datos=form.cleaned_data
            email=EmailMessage(cuerpo,'body', to=['pajaritosami88@gmail.com'])
            email.send()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
```

Compruebo que la cabecera del mensaje es lo que ponga en la variable cuerpo en el email (y aunque puse como argumento el first_name, lo que veo en la cabecera es el username). Ovbiamente lo que quiero es que se envie a nombre del usuario que tiene abierta la sesión, no el usuario que decida yo.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema de concepto con esto.

El correo electrónico es simple, tiene 3 protocolos 2 para recibir: [IMAP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) y [POP3](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol)
y otro para enviar: [SMTP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)

Con el protocolo SMTP es posible hacer lo que tu pides ya que solo consta de 4 parámetros que son strings:
-Quien lo envía
-A Donde va dirigido
-Titulo
-Cuerpo del mensaje

Si tu te montas tu propio SMTP el parametro 'quien lo envia' es modificable, pero si usas un SMTP de terceros (en este caso el de google) no te va a dejar modificar ese paramentro por temas de suplantación de identidad.

**OJO** Por que al menos en mi país (españa), suplantar una identidad es ilegal. No se exactamente si a tu aplicación se le aplicaria. Pero cuidado con esto.

Por tanto: Si configuras un SMTP de terceros, tu mail siempre será enviado por lo que hayas configurado en EMAIL_HOST_USER o en su defecto la cuenta que tengas asociada a las contraseñas del servicio SMTP que estés usando.

Yo te recomiendo que lo pongas en el cuerpo o en el titulo, tipo el 'usuario Pajaritos te ha dejado un mensaje' y que dentro del cuerpo, indiques a la cuenta de mail donde responder. (Teniendo en cuenta que tus condiciones de servicio deberían cubrir esta casuistica)

Comment: Es decir, como utilizo 'smtp.gmail.com' no se me permite indicar el email del emisor.

Comment: En ese caso, hare lo de que el "asunto" del email ponga el nombre del usuario. ¿Como hago para sustituir title por el nickname del usuario?

Comment: @MiguelAlparez, te recomiendo que hagas una nueva pregunta. Este espacio es solo para comentarios, no para hacer preguntas.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez esto esta resuelto, no?

Comment: @Zartch Esto se resolvio en una pregunta posterior, para ser exactos.

Comment: Pues acepta alguna y cieralo que si no se quedan abiertas las preguntas

Answer (score 0):

Ya he arreglado lo que pretendia de que se viese el nombre del usuario en la cabecera.

Hay que modificar esto en views.py:

```
class contacto(View):
    def get(self,request):
        form=correo()
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
    def post(self,request):
        form=correo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cuerpo="Mensaje de "+str(**request.user**)
            datos=form.cleaned_data
            email=EmailMessage(cuerpo,'body', to=['pajaritosami88@gmail.com'])
            email.send()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
```

Así se sabe quien envio el mensaje.